# Cut, Copy, Paste, Select All Functions - How to simply allow default handling after clicking on menu item?

Tags: python, clipboard, gtk3, pygtk, pygobject

The "Ctrl+C" and "Ctrl+V" shortcuts (as well as the "right click menu") are available by default in any GTK application, for example a simple hello world app with only a SourceView (see below). 
But if I add a menu item "Edit->Copy" and assign the "Ctrl+C" accelerator to it and a corresponding callback function, than it obviously stops working since I am intercepting the signal with my own method. So, how can I trigger the default cut/copy/paste/select_all functionalities inside my custom method?

*Note: returning `False` works for the Paste function but not for Copy/Cut/Select All*

Simple example - In this case all functions (cut/copy/paste/select all) work fine.

```py
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
gi.require_version('GtkSource', '3.0') 
from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk, Pango, GObject, GtkSource

class MyOwnApp(Gtk.Window):

    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="Hello World")
        self.set_default_size(500, 500)

        self.vbox = Gtk.VBox()

        editor = GtkSource.View.new()
        editor.set_show_line_numbers(True)
        editor.set_auto_indent(True)
        editor_buffer = editor.get_buffer()
        self.vbox.pack_start(editor, False, False, 0)

        self.add(self.vbox)

 win = MyOwnApp()
 win.connect("destroy", Gtk.main_quit)
 win.show_all()
 Gtk.main()
```

If I add a menu item with a callback they don't work anymore.

```py
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
gi.require_version('GtkSource', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk, Pango, GObject, GtkSource

class MyOwnApp(Gtk.Window):

    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="Hello World")

        self.set_default_size(900, 900)

        box_outer = Gtk.VBox()

        # MENUBAR setup
        menuBar = Gtk.MenuBar()
        # Set accelerators
        agr = Gtk.AccelGroup()
        self.add_accel_group(agr)

        # File menu
        file_menu_dropdown = Gtk.MenuItem("File")
        menuBar.append(file_menu_dropdown)
        file_menu = Gtk.Menu()
        file_menu_dropdown.set_submenu(file_menu)

        # File menu Items
        file_exit = Gtk.MenuItem("Exit")
        key, mod = Gtk.accelerator_parse("<Control>Q")
        file_exit.add_accelerator("activate", agr, key, mod, Gtk.AccelFlags.VISIBLE)
        file_exit.connect("activate", self.quit)

        file_menu.append(file_exit)

        # Edit menu
        edit_menu_dropdown = Gtk.MenuItem("Edit")
        menuBar.append(edit_menu_dropdown)
        edit_menu = Gtk.Menu()
        edit_menu_dropdown.set_submenu(edit_menu)

        # Edit menu Items
        edit_cut = Gtk.MenuItem("Cut")
        key, mod = Gtk.accelerator_parse("<Control>X")
        edit_cut.add_accelerator("activate", agr, key, mod, Gtk.AccelFlags.VISIBLE)
        edit_cut.connect("activate", self.on_toolbutton_cut_clicked)

        edit_copy = Gtk.MenuItem("Copy")
        key, mod = Gtk.accelerator_parse("<Control>C")
        edit_copy.add_accelerator("activate", agr, key, mod, Gtk.AccelFlags.VISIBLE)
        edit_copy.connect("activate", self.on_toolbutton_copy_clicked)

        edit_paste = Gtk.MenuItem("Paste")
        key, mod = Gtk.accelerator_parse("<Control>V")
        edit_paste.add_accelerator("activate", agr, key, mod, Gtk.AccelFlags.VISIBLE)
        edit_paste.connect("activate", self.on_toolbutton_paste_clicked)

        edit_select_all = Gtk.MenuItem("Select All")
        key, mod = Gtk.accelerator_parse("<Control>A")
        edit_select_all.add_accelerator("activate", agr, key, mod, Gtk.AccelFlags.VISIBLE)
        edit_select_all.connect("activate", self.on_toolbutton_select_all_clicked)

        edit_menu.append(edit_select_all)
        edit_menu.append(edit_cut)
        edit_menu.append(edit_copy)
        edit_menu.append(edit_paste)

        box_outer.pack_start(menuBar, False, False, 0)

        # SourceView
        editor = GtkSource.View.new()
        editor.set_show_line_numbers(True)
        editor.set_auto_indent(True)
        editor_buffer = editor.get_buffer()
        box_outer.pack_start(editor, True, True, 0)

        self.add(box_outer)

    def quit(self,widget=None):
        Gtk.main_quit()

    def on_toolbutton_select_all_clicked(self, widget):
        return False

    def on_toolbutton_cut_clicked(self, widget):
        return False

    def on_toolbutton_copy_clicked(self, widget):
        return False

    def on_toolbutton_paste_clicked(self, widget):
        return False

win = MyOwnApp()
win.connect("destroy", Gtk.main_quit)
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After too many hours of research, I'm happy to post this solution for all the GTK enthusiast out there!!
*Thanks to @SivaGuru for contributing!!*

With this solution, you can use the cut/copy/paste/selectAll functions across multiple widgets inside a window (with both `Gtk.Entry` and `GtkSource.View`).
The key point is that these two widgets use different methods for the cut/copy/paste/selectAll functionalities, but *(as expected) they both have default methods to manage these basic functionalities*. No need to reinvent the wheel.
Note: The `Gtk.Entry` widget inherits from the `Gtk.Editable` interface, which has all the necessary functions to fallback to the default handling of cut/copy/past/selectAll.

```py
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
gi.require_version('GtkSource', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk, GtkSource

class MyWindow(Gtk.Window):

    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="Hello World")

        self.set_default_size(900, 900)

        box_outer = Gtk.VBox()

        # MENUBAR setup
        menuBar = Gtk.MenuBar()
        # Set accelerators
        agr = Gtk.AccelGroup()
        self.add_accel_group(agr)

        # File menu
        file_menu_dropdown = Gtk.MenuItem("File")
        menuBar.append(file_menu_dropdown)
        file_menu = Gtk.Menu()
        file_menu_dropdown.set_submenu(file_menu)

        #File menu Items
        file_exit = Gtk.MenuItem("Exit")
        key, mod = Gtk.accelerator_parse("<Control>Q")
        file_exit.add_accelerator("activate", agr, key, mod, Gtk.AccelFlags.VISIBLE)
        file_exit.connect("activate", self.quit)

        file_menu.append(file_exit)

        # Edit menu
        edit_menu_dropdown = Gtk.MenuItem("Edit")
        menuBar.append(edit_menu_dropdown)
        edit_menu = Gtk.Menu()
        edit_menu_dropdown.set_submenu(edit_menu)

        # Edit menu Items
        edit_cut = Gtk.MenuItem("Cut")
        key, mod = Gtk.accelerator_parse("<Control>X")
        edit_cut.add_accelerator("activate", agr, key, mod, Gtk.AccelFlags.VISIBLE)
        edit_cut.connect("activate", self.on_toolbutton_cut_clicked)

        edit_copy = Gtk.MenuItem("Copy")
        key, mod = Gtk.accelerator_parse("<Control>C")
        edit_copy.add_accelerator("activate", agr, key, mod, Gtk.AccelFlags.VISIBLE)
        edit_copy.connect("activate", self.on_toolbutton_copy_clicked)

        edit_paste = Gtk.MenuItem("Paste")
        key, mod = Gtk.accelerator_parse("<Control>V")
        edit_paste.add_accelerator("activate", agr, key, mod, Gtk.AccelFlags.VISIBLE)
        edit_paste.connect("activate", self.on_toolbutton_paste_clicked)

        edit_select_all = Gtk.MenuItem("Select All")
        key, mod = Gtk.accelerator_parse("<Control>A")
        edit_select_all.add_accelerator("activate", agr, key, mod, Gtk.AccelFlags.VISIBLE)
        edit_select_all.connect("activate", self.on_toolbutton_select_all_clicked)

        edit_menu.append(edit_select_all)
        edit_menu.append(edit_cut)
        edit_menu.append(edit_copy)
        edit_menu.append(edit_paste)

        box_outer.pack_start(menuBar, False, False, 0)

        entry = Gtk.Entry()
        box_outer.pack_start(entry, False, False, 0)

        editor = GtkSource.View.new()
        editor.set_show_line_numbers(True)
        editor.set_auto_indent(True)
        box_outer.pack_start(editor, True, True, 0)

        self.clipboard = Gtk.Clipboard.get(Gdk.SELECTION_CLIPBOARD)

        self.add(box_outer)

    def quit(self,widget=None):
        Gtk.main_quit()

    def on_toolbutton_select_all_clicked(self, widget):
        focusedWidget = self.get_focus()
        if focusedWidget is not None:
            if focusedWidget.has_focus():
                if str(type(focusedWidget)) == "<class 'gi.repository.Gtk.Entry'>":
                    focusedWidget.select_region(0, -1)
                elif str(type(focusedWidget)) == "<class 'gi.repository.GtkSource.View'>":
                    editor_buffer = focusedWidget.get_buffer()
                    editor_buffer.select_range(editor_buffer.get_start_iter(), editor_buffer.get_end_iter())
                else:
                    pass

    def on_toolbutton_cut_clicked(self, widget):
        focusedWidget = self.get_focus()
        if focusedWidget is not None:
            if focusedWidget.has_focus():
                if str(type(focusedWidget)) == "<class 'gi.repository.Gtk.Entry'>":
                    focusedWidget.cut_clipboard()
                elif str(type(focusedWidget)) == "<class 'gi.repository.GtkSource.View'>":
                    editor_buffer = focusedWidget.get_buffer()
                    editor_buffer.cut_clipboard(self.clipboard, editor_buffer)
                else:
                    pass

    def on_toolbutton_copy_clicked(self, widget):
        focusedWidget = self.get_focus()
        if focusedWidget is not None:
            if focusedWidget.has_focus():
                if str(type(focusedWidget)) == "<class 'gi.repository.Gtk.Entry'>":
                    focusedWidget.copy_clipboard()
                elif str(type(focusedWidget)) == "<class 'gi.repository.GtkSource.View'>":
                    editor_buffer = focusedWidget.get_buffer()
                    editor_buffer.copy_clipboard(self.clipboard)
                else:
                    pass

    def on_toolbutton_paste_clicked(self, widget):
        focusedWidget = self.get_focus()
        if focusedWidget is not None:
            if focusedWidget.has_focus():
                if str(type(focusedWidget)) == "<class 'gi.repository.Gtk.Entry'>":
                    focusedWidget.paste_clipboard()
                elif str(type(focusedWidget)) == "<class 'gi.repository.GtkSource.View'>":
                    editor_buffer = focusedWidget.get_buffer()
                    editor_buffer.paste_clipboard(self.clipboard, None, editor_buffer)
                else:
                    pass

win = MyWindow()
win.connect("destroy", Gtk.main_quit)
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

Answer (score 1):

. Calling the action-specific functions in editor_buffer(GtkSourceBuffer) which simulate the default handling of (cut/copy/paste/select all).

```
    def on_toolbutton_select_all_clicked(self, widget):
    print("Select all")
    if self.editor.is_focus():
        self.editor_buffer.select_range(self.editor_buffer.get_start_iter(), self.editor_buffer.get_end_iter())
    else:
        self.entry.select_region(0,-1)
    return True

def on_toolbutton_cut_clicked(self, widget):
    print("Cut")
    if self.editor.is_focus():
        self.editor_buffer.cut_clipboard(self.clipboard,self.editor_buffer)
    else:
        self.entry.emit("cut-clipboard")
    return True

def on_toolbutton_copy_clicked(self, widget):
    if self.editor.is_focus():
        self.editor_buffer.copy_clipboard(self.clipboard)
    else:
        self.entry.emit("copy-clipboard")
    return True

def on_toolbutton_paste_clicked(self, widget):
    if self.editor.is_focus():
        self.editor_buffer.paste_clipboard(self.clipboard, None, self.editor_buffer)
    else:
        self.entry.emit("paste-clipboard")
    return True
```

for more details, you can look into this (https://developer.gnome.org/pygtk/stable/class-gtktextbuffer.html). for other widgets emitting signals work and this implementation should work for SourceView also.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it works **partially**. By default, cut/copy/paste works across different widgets (for example let's say that, beside the gtksourceview, there is also an entry widget) - With your solution if you place the cursor inside the entry widget and press Ctrl+A, then the text in the gtksourceview will be selected instead of that of the entry widget. Same issue for the copy functionality etc.

Comment: ohh ok..  could you share a sample code where the method I suggested doesn't work I will look into it and try to give a better resolution for it.

Comment: Here is a gist with the code (including your suggestions): https://gist.github.com/gittix09/a0561c63d0d4f16d0e322d1fcfc8910e. For example, try writing something in both the widgets (entry and sourceview) and then (with the cursor focused in the entry) press `Ctrl+A`

Comment: what would be the expected behaviour.. when you are typing a text in gtkEntry and click on menu item "edit_select_all" should it select all in Gtkentry or in GtkSource View ?

Comment: If the user is typing inside the entry widget, then it should select all the text in the GTKEntry and not in the sourceview. Just like if you select some text in the Entry widget and click the `Edit->Copy` menu, then the app should copy the selected text of the Entry. And so on, you get the idea. Side note: the right-click menu (context menu) by default also works this way, so it would be weird if the app menu and the `Ctrl+[key]` shortcuts worked in a different way.

Comment: I don't know if this has any proper solution or not. As from my searches, I didn't get any proper solution for this. But i can suggest a way for this to work:-  1) don't connect the accel group this will make the default functionality available 2) and in the respective callback functions of menu items do "is_focus"  check it see for currently focused widget. and then do the respective handling or just try emitting a signal (gtk_widget_event). This will be hard to handle if you have a log of text widgets in the application

Comment: That could be a solution... but supposing that I'm able to discriminate between the focused widgets, how can I retrieve **only the selected** text inside a `Gtk.Entry` widget? The `Gtk.EntryBuffer` (see [docs](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/Gtk-3.0/classes/EntryBuffer.html#Gtk.EntryBuffer)) doesn’t seem to have any method to retrieve the selection (you can only retrieve all the text).

Comment: I finally found a solution!! The `Gtk.Entry` widget inherits from the `Gtk.Editable` interface, which has all the necessary functions to fallback to the default handling of cut/copy/past/selectAll.

Comment: The modified code also uses above also uses  Gtk.Editable but only for selecting all text

Comment: I've shared the code of the complete working solution. Feel free to write any suggestion.